# kendo dropdown list casecadefrom

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, cascade, kendo-dropdown

I have three kendo drop downlist as below

1)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ProgrammeID)
.HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
.Name("ProgrammeID") 
.DataTextField("DegreeName") 
.DataValueField("Id") 
.OptionLabel("Select Below...")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetProgramme", "AptitudeTset").Data("filterProgramme");
            })

            .ServerFiltering(true); 
        })
.SelectedIndex(0)
.CascadeFrom("FacultyID")
)
```

2)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SpecializationID)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
.Name("SpecializationID") 
.DataTextField("SpecializationNameID") 
.DataValueField("SpecializationID") 
.OptionLabel("Select Below...")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetSpecialization", "Subject").Data("filterSpecialization"); 
            })

            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
.SelectedIndex(0) 
.CascadeFrom("ProgrammeID")
)
```

3)

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SemesterID)

.HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
.OptionLabel("Select Below...")
.Name("SemesterID") 
.DataTextField("SemesterName") 
.DataValueField("SemesterID")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetSemester", "StudentRSRegistration").Data("loadSemester");
            })  

            .ServerFiltering(true); 
        })
.SelectedIndex(0) 
.CascadeFrom("SpecializationID")    
.CascadeFrom("ProgrammeID"`enter code here`)        
)
```

in here my 3rd DDL load based on 1st & 2nd DDL. But some times 2nd DDL may not has values. It can be empty..1st DDL always has values. My problem is, when 2nd DDL is null value my 3rd DDL not loading. But I want to load my 3rd DDL always. Because SemesterID is Requires. SemesterID depend on programmeID **or/and** SpecializationID. That's why some times 2nd DDl may have null values.

Comment: I don't think the widget knows how to handle multiple CascadeFrom on 1 DropDown. You will have to handle the CascadeFrom logic manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using Ajax call..I used 2nd DDL Cascade Event Handel like below
**.Events(m=>m.Cascade("cascadesp"))**

Now my 2nd DDL

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SpecializationID)

    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
    .Name("SpecializationID") 
    .DataTextField("SpecializationNameID") 
    .DataValueField("SpecializationID")
    .OptionLabel("Select Below...")
            .DataSource(source =>
            {

                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetSpecialization", "Subject").Data("filterSpecialization"); 
                })

                .ServerFiltering(true); 
            })
    .Events(m=>m.Cascade("cascadesp"))
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .CascadeFrom("ProgrammeID")
)
```

my ajax call is

```
function cascadesp()
{
    getSemesterID($("#ProgrammeID").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),$("#SpecializationID").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),$("#SpecializationLevelID").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),$("#IntakeID").data("kendoDropDownList").value(),$("#intakeYear").val());
}

function getSemesterID(ProgrammeID, SpecializationID, SpecializationLevelID, IntakeID, intakeYear)
{
    var ddl = $('#SemesterID').data("kendoDropDownList");
    var URL = "/StudentRSRegistration/GetSemester/";
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        data: JSON.stringify({ ProgrammeID: ProgrammeID, SpecializationID: SpecializationID, SpecializationLevelID: SpecializationLevelID, IntakeID: IntakeID, intakeYear: intakeYear }),
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            ddl.setDataSource(data);
        }
    });
}
```

now my SemeterID DDL is loding Propely